# Why python gevent.joinall execute all greenlets

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets

I have the following Python code:

```
>>> import gevent
>>> from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
>>>
>>> def fooFn(k):
...     return 'gevent_'+k
...
>>> threads = []
>>> threads.append(gevent.spawn(fooFn,'0'))
>>> threads.append(gevent.spawn(fooFn,'1'))
>>>
>>> gevent.joinall([threads[1]])
>>>
>>> print threads[1].value
gevent_1
>>> print threads[0].value
gevent_0
>>>
```

As seen above, `threads[0].value` got a proper value from the `fooFn`. This means that the `threads[0]` greenlet was executed.

Why did this this happen when I passed only the `threads[1]` greenlet to `gevent.joinall`?

How can I make sure that only those greenlets are executed which are actually passed to `gevent.joinall`?

Comment: `gevent.joinall()` only waits for the greenlets passed in as parameters to finish and joins it with the main thread. To the best of my knowledge, it doesn't block execution of any of the other threads - simply tells the main thread not to exit until the greenlets have finished running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your greenlets are scheduled *immediately* when you call `greenlet.spawn()`. In other words, they are created and started at once when you call `spawn()`. That's why the first greenlet is finished running - both greenlets were executing from the moment you spawned them, and by the time you got around to looking up the results from greenlet 1, both were done executing.

`gevent.joinall()` doesn't execute greenlets - it only tells the main thread (the one that actually `spawn`ed them) to wait for the ones passed in as parameters to finish running. Not calling `joinall` runs the risk of the main thread finishing and exiting before the results of the greenlets in `joinall()` has been reached, and then who's going to handle their results?

Here, you did two things that you should change in order to see `gevents` behave like you want:

- You called `joinall()` in the console REPL, rather than from a script.

  Here, the main thread - the REPL - is *guaranteed* to not finish before the
  greenlets return, because the REPL only ends when you call `exit()`
  or indicate EOF. In a script with no immediate user interaction, however, you don't have that luxury - execution ends when there's nothing left in the script to do. That's why we call `join()` to ensure that the main thread never exits and leaves your greenlet hanging with no parent to return to.

  There's no point in calling `joinall()` in the console (although if you want a guarantee you'll have results from the greenlet when you next call a function on the greenlet, it's a good idea)
- You shouldn't have called `spawn()` if you want to guarantee only greenlet 1 is executed while greenlet 2 isn't. Instead, [read what the docs say](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html):

  > To start a new greenlet, pass the target function and its arguments to
  >   Greenlet constructor and call start():
  >
  > `>>> g = Greenlet(myfunction, 'arg1', 'arg2', kwarg1=1)`
  >
  > `>>> g.start()`
  >
  > or use classmethod `spawn()` which is a shortcut that does the same:
  >
  > `>>> g = Greenlet.spawn(myfunction, 'arg1', 'arg2', kwarg1=1)`

Using `start` to indicate the greenlet should start running at this moment  is a good idea. So: create two greenlet objects, and only call `start` on one of them to have only that one execute.